# Merge multiple branches in single branch in git

Tags: git, version-control

I have a master branch and multiple test branches. I need to create a local test(some branch)branch and merge all the existing test branches into the newly created local branch and resolve the conflicts.

So far, I have created a local branch after cloning as follows:

- `git clone <remote url>`
- `git branch <some branch>`

Now, how do I proceed further? I new to git. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Be sure to read the git book (google for it) and to familiarize yourself with `git help` as well. That would clear up many of your questions and give you a chance too really learn.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to base your merge-target branch off `master`, you could try the following:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b test-merge    # create the new branch
```

And then just merge each of the test branches into `test-merge`:

```
git merge test1
# resolve conflicts, commit
git merge test2
# resolve again, etc.
```

Comment: If I missed something, drop a comment and I'm happy to update.

Comment: I have already created a local test branch using `git branch some_branch` and now I want to get all the tests branches from master and merge them

Comment: What does `git checkout -b` mean?

Comment: `git checkout -b` creates a new branch from the current branch you are on as a starting point.

Comment: I guess it `git checkout -b` creates a local branch? but whats wrong when using `git branch <branch name>`?

Comment: @kittu I think you can use that too, but the advantage of `git checkout -b` is that it creates the new branch _and_ switches to it.  This works in your case, because you plan on using it right away.

Comment: And then `git merge test1` gets the `test1` branch from master into new created local branch??

Comment: @kittu Yes, that's right.  `git merge test1` merges `test1` into the current branch, and then you may have to resolve merge conflicts.

Comment: All this is happening locally(in my system) right? I hope not on master or remote?

Comment: Yes, Git is predominantly a local tool.  Even when you merge the "remote" `master` into your local `master` when you pull, you are actually using a local remote tracking branch.

Comment: One last thing, I have multiple test branches with names starting with `Test-PPE-125059` where suffix is dynamic ID. Is it possible to merge all the test branches at once using regex(star * symbol) like `git merge Test-PPE-*`??

Comment: AFAIK you can only merge one branch at a time, _but_ you could certainly try to automate things by writing a script which iterates over your test branches.  The thing is though, that if you get a ton of ugly merge conflicts, those would likely have to handled manually, so full automation here may not be possible.